# How to hide border flickity in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, slider, flickity

anyone please help, how to hide border flickity slider in chrome. The border just show in Browser Chrome only. may be like this :

[image]

or u can visit my blog : aqiqoh-syafaat.blogspot.co.id
thanks

Answer (score 2):

To remove the outline from just flickity elements you can add the following css

```
.flickity-enabled:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

As others have said removing this globally is bad for accessibility. If you use the dots or nav features for flickity you would ideally add focus to these elements.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please tell exactly where how you can see that border.

Generally this border appears as outline on focus(if), you can set

```
*:focus{
outline:none;
}
```

This will remove that blue border from everywhere.

or simply outline:none; on element or its pseudo class 
(Use !important if needed.)

Comment: Please select the answer as correct answer @rohmat. :)

Comment: Using the `*:focus` is not a good solution.. When someone is using a keyboard they have absolutely no idea what element is selected.